# How do I omit a key in type with dynamic field

Tags: typescript

How do I define `UserValue` type that omit `id` field from `User`

```
interface User {
  [x: string]: any
  avatarUrl?: string
  bio?: string
  company?: string
  email?: string
  emailVerified?: boolean
  firstName?: string
  id: types.TimeUuid
}
type UserValue = Omit<User, 'id'>
```

Result of current solution will be

```
type UserValue = {
    [x: string]: any;
    [x: number]: any;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it correctly but do you want to create UserValue type that would be the same as user except `id` field which shouldn't be present in UserValue? If so - you could simply create `interface UserValue` defining all the field currently present in User except `id` and then change User interface to the following: `interface User extends UserValue { id: types.TimeUuid }`

Comment: You understood right. I would like to have solution without changing types that already exists. But could work. Thanks

Comment: But that's exactly what `type UserValue = Omit<User, 'id'>` does...

Comment: The index - `[x: string]: any` - is causing the problem, because `Omit` relies on `keyof T` which in the case of a generic string indexed object is just `string`. So all your named properties are being collapsed into `string`. I would just get rid of the index, you shouldn't need to access unnamed properties on a well-defined object like this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case You could try to make all fields optional.
That will allow you to create object without id field,
but Pawel's suggestion in comments is better.

```
type AllOptional<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]?: Type[Property];
};


interface User {
  [x: string]: any
  avatarUrl?: string
  bio?: string
  company?: string
  email?: string
  emailVerified?: boolean
  firstName?: string
  id: number
}

type UserValue = AllOptional<User>

const x: UserValue = {
  email: "xxx",
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA8mYBLA9gOwIZwDwAq4EAfFALxQDeAUFFANoAKATupC6FKplANYQQ6AGZQikALoB+AFxjizNh1ASA3DQC+6mjR7AILYdgDG0AKoBnA9TqMAHnIvAWPAOYS52TCFvYAbtjA2CxmLHCyUE4umK62AEYYEVFutsboALZgXiBJzin0EOnYqOGOeTG2hcVwAGoGqMKoEAAmEXHo6HAQXraNLE4ActjpELnRsfSozXKYAK7pcQaaOqCQUJYGNbiz0JTwSCgYOPgbLCQ6aZhOUA7rVixbcDsUNgVFJXIARHY-nwA0yx0NCAA)

Answer (score 0):

`type S = 'foo' | string` will resolve to `type S = string`.

And that's the root of your problem. By including `[x: string]`, you make it impossible to `Omit` any properties from `User`. To understand why, take a look at the definition for `Omit`:

```ts
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Translate this to your `User` interface:

```ts
// Simplified User:
interface User {
  [x: string]: any
  etc?: string
  id: number
}

// This
type UserValue = Omit<User, 'id'>;
// is equivalent to
type UserValue = Pick<User, Exclude<keyof User, 'id'>>;
```

Because `[x: string]` allows for any `string` (or `number`, but not `Symbol`) property accessor, `keyof User` allows for *any `string` (or `number`) value*. Excluding the type `'id'` from `string` is still `string`.

```ts
type NotId = Exclude<string, 'id'>
//   ^^^^^ type NotId = string
```

So what you end up with is a type that picks all string accessor properties from interface `User` giving you

```ts
type UserValue = {
    [x: string]: any;
    [x: number]: any;
};
```

So `Omit` will not work on `User`, at least not the way you want.

---

#### Solution

If you have been using the `User` type in your code, you don't want to change the definition. Instead, I recommend creating a base interface that does not include `[x: string]: any` for `User` to extend:

```ts
interface UserBase {
  avatarUrl?: string
  // ...
  id: types.TimeUuid
}

interface User extends UserBase {
  [x: string]: any
}

type UserValue = Omit<UserModel, 'id'>
```

Or, don't use `Omit` at all:

```ts
interface UserValue {
  [x: string]: any
  avatarUrl?: string
  // ...
  firstName?: string
}

interface User extends UserValue {
  id: types.TimeUuid
}
```

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyyA2gB4Bcy6YUoA5gLqVwgCeBRcAbnGHFKigAbAPyVqtEHQ7IARsAD2YqjXoyECgLYAHFq2US1hZBE1xgo8aqkzT5oQDVowGMAgATZbIUKhEFjKuUNQAcnCaEAbW0sbA7pQgAK6astAEAL4EBGCs2igY0ADSEKzIALzIANYlCjBomFAA3Nm5KCEKYACS7uXIAKKkCEKJ7hAAPAVQxawANMgA5HHzAHwtecgACsAI1e6TvVs7Ew1z7V3uq-g565MOcMMoFYeVx9BzA0Mj49WstfVvCyWy0uWXwoyG-BQmgU7kSfmQAGVfIkwIoQDgZKBILBEPkGgAhOCYIh4YycHh8ATCKKSGJEIjyJRWWkyIgaHR6GlGekmMwWLk2Mm8+xOWiuDxeHx+AJCoKhcKRZnc+lxBLJVJQGSZfCY8DQeBIf5QEykSAgdzoI2E4kYoVkJVSJjIPRa0FEa546B3B69ADymmAYFeUGtKDmi3cKwyBCAA) exploring these concepts and the solution.